# Is https://stackoverrun.com/ an illegal page that takes info from stackoverflow.com in order to cheat users?

Tags: discussion, legal, scraping

I found this question on an site that already was unknown for me. It seems it is kind of a **phishing site**

https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/7514014

The evidence is that the question is the same that stackoverflow's one:

[Combining orderByChild and equalTo in Firebase queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369731/combining-orderbychild-and-equalto-in-firebase-queries)

The site is also appearing in very high position in Google's search:

[image]

**Also, the site told me that my pc was infected.** I don't have now the screenshot but it seemed to be the typical fake message in order to install any malicious software.

Comment: This site uses attribution. So they are technically respecting the license as long as they offer the content under the same or a compatible license as it is offered on SO.

Comment: If the site is trying to install malware, you can report it to Google through this form: https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/?hl=en
It then has a chance of getting added to a Chrome blocklist.

Comment: Following the links through to MSE, there is a note about a site serving Malware.  So if you find one, there is additional directions in the MSE post but you can report it to Google: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport